# How to use RKObjectMapping as a standalone library

Tags: ios, json, restkit, object-object-mapping

I use AFNetworking to write a RESTful client.
An then use JSONKit to parse the response data to a NSDictionary.

Example:

```
- (void)postPath:(NSString *)path
  parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
     success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject, NSDictionary* jsonDictionary))success
     failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
    {

    [self.client postPath:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary* jsonDictionary = [self.jsonDecoder objectWithData:responseObject];

        // do the object-mapping works            

        success(operation, responseObject, jsonDictionary);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure(failure, error);
    }];
```

}

How can I use the benefit of RKObjectMapping from RESTKit as a standalone library to do the object-mapping?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be specific about what your problem is and what you've tried to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use RestKit it will replace all of your current code. RestKit is built on top of `AFNetworking` so you would post your object from RestKit and map the resulting data back into that object. Whether this is useful depends on the purpose of your POST. What you have currently can be trimmed a little if you don't use RestKit by using `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

In general, the question boils down to:

1. What is the data you're posting and expect to receive
2. How complicated is your mapping

If the mapping isn't complex, RestKit is probably overkill. From your code it looks like you're making a simple post so that should be fine (and you would construct your mappings to update the object you're posting, even though no data was actually taken from that object to make the request).

Comment: I know RESTKit is build on top of AFNetworking. But RESTKit is too heavy for me to use. But I can't find a good-enough object-mapping library than RESTKit. So I'm thinking only to use the Object-mapping benefit from RESTKit. And AFJSONRequestOperation does not do the object-mapping jobs.

Comment: RestKit only adds mapping on top really, if you want to use the mapping then the easiest approach is to directly use RestKit for everything than trying to do the download yourself and then push that data into RestKit (which is contrived).